# Parse a Soap Response in an Oracle 11g Function

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, oracle11g, clob

I have a function in Oracle 11g which uses UTL_HTTP to consume a web service.  I am storing the SOAP response in a CLOB.

After researching for hours, I still have not found a way to directly parse XML fields in the clob.

The SOAP response in the clob looks something like this:

```
(CLOB) <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GET_PERMITOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/DBUSER/MYSERV">
      <RETURN>
        <STATUS_CODES>
          <stat>REC</stat>
        </STATUS_CODES>
      </RETURN>
    </GET_PERMITOutput>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to be able to parse that value "REC" out (in other cases there will be multiple status codes) and do something with it in my function.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it would probably be easier to store XML in an `XMLType` column.  Otherwise, in order to parse the data, you're going to have to convert the `CLOB` to an `XMLType` at runtime.

Assuming you're starting with a `CLOB`, however, you should be able to do something like

```
select xmltype( xml_response ).extract('//stat/text()',
                                       'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' ||
                                       'xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/DBUSER/MYSERV').getStringVal()
 from foo
```

to extract the data.  For my test, I created a table with a `CLOB`

```
SQL> create table foo(
  2    xml_response clob
  3  );

Table created.
```

Inserted your sample data

```
SQL> insert into foo values( '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  2  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  3    <soap:Body>
  4      <GET_PERMITOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/DBUSER/MYSERV">
  5        <RETURN>
  6          <STATUS_CODES>
  7            <stat>REC</stat>
  8          </STATUS_CODES>
  9        </RETURN>
 10      </GET_PERMITOutput>
 11    </soap:Body>
 12  </soap:Envelope>');

1 row created.
```

And then wrote the query to extract it

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select xmltype( xml_response ).extract('//stat/text()',
  2                                         'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' ||
  3                                         'xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/DBUSER/MYSERV').getStringVal()
  4*  from foo
SQL> /

XMLTYPE(XML_RESPONSE).EXTRACT('//STAT/TEXT()','XMLNS:SOAP="HTTP://SCHEMAS.XMLSOA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REC
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I think that way would work-- I actually found a workaround so that I don't have to make a temp table to insert the xml.  I also used XMLTable, which is one of the newer 11g XQuery functions.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jcohler - Note that my solution doesn't require that you have a `CLOB` in a table-- you could do exactly the same thing with a local variable that is declared as a `CLOB`.  I was just using a table because it wasn't obvious whether you had a `CLOB` in a table or in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this without having to insert into a temp table.  My function gets a SOAP response in the form of a CLOB, and stores it in a variable called "resp", which is used below without inserting the clob into anything temporary:

```
with t as (select xmltype(resp) xcol from dual)
  select status
  into tmp FROM t, XDBUSER.XDBUSER_XML
     , XMLTABLE( XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap", 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/DBUSER/MYSERV' as "a")
        ,'/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/a:GET_PERMITOutput/a:RETURN/a:STATUS_CODES'
              PASSING XMLTYPE.CreateXML(XML_CLOB)
              COLUMNS "STATUS"  VARCHAR2(500) PATH 'a:stat');
```

A clob is a safer way to handle the soap request than an XMLType, because the data returned may be longer than 32767 bytes.

Comment: Neither a `CLOB` nor an `XMLType` are limited to 32767 bytes-- an `XMLType` is just a `CLOB` with a bunch of XML utility functions wrapped around it.  An `XMLType` is the preferred way to handle XML in PL/SQL.  A `VARCHAR2` in PL/SQL is limited to 32767.